# querydsl subquery on @ElementCollection

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have a problem with QueryDsl and an @ElementCollection

Say I have a root class

```
@Entity
public class Root {
    @Id
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "VAL", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROOT_ID"))
    @OrderBy("prop")
    public SortedSet<Val> vals = new TreeSet<>();
```

And a Values

```
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Embeddable
public class Val implements Comparable<Val>{
   public String prop;
   public LocalDateTime timestamp;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Val o) {
      return prop.compareTo(o.prop);
  }
```

}

The sql query I want to perfom is like:

```
select * FROM VAL v, ROOT r
    WHERE
        r.ID = v.ROOT_ID
        and v.TIMESTAMP in (select max(va.TIMESTAMP) from VAL va GROUP BY va.ROOT_ID)
        and v.PROP = 'value'
```

The Problem when I try to translate this to querydsl is that QVal is not an 'EntityPathBase' but a 'BeanPath'. And it can't be used in a from.

The querydsl would be something like

```
QRoot root = QRoot.root;

JPQLQuery<Root> value = JPAExpressions.select(root)
    .from(root)
    .innerJoin(root.vals, QVal.val)
    .where(QVal.val.timestamp.in(
        JPAExpressions.select(QVal.val.timestamp.max())
                    .from(QVal.val)   <---- does not work !
                    .groupBy(QVal.val))
                    .and(QVal.val.prop.eq("value"))
            );

repository.findAll(root.in(value));
```

Comment: This should be possible. Is your Val entity `Comparable` by any chance? And is it an `@Entity` or a `@ManagedType`? I am asking because there is a metamodel generation bug regarding Comparable entities that might cause this: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2572 .